# How to check if an extjs superbox is loaded completetly

Tags: extjs

I have a superbox(multi select combobox) which works fine..

The request for combo load goes when I click on it to select anything.
Now I want to remove an element called ABC from it.

I tried to add a listener to it as follows, but this event it never fires

```
listeners: {
                        onLoad: function () {
                            alert('ok');
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: is it possible to put in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The combo doesn't have a `load` event. Its store does. Make sure you are listening to the right object.